# a little bit confusion in the Code

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

hi i am reading a book named **" Beginning Visual C# 2012 Programming "** in this book in chapter 4 under lopping section they have given followng example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChapterFourExcerciseFour
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double balance, interestRate, targetBalance;
            int totalYears = 0;

            //reading balance from the console and saving it into the balance
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your balance");
            balance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            //reading interesrrate from the console and saving it into tht interesrrate
            Console.WriteLine("What is your current interest rate");
            interestRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            //reading targetbalance from the console and saving it int the targetbalance
            Console.WriteLine("What balancce would you like to have");
            targetBalance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            do
            {
                balance *= interestRate;
                ++totalYears;
            }
            while (balance < targetBalance);
            Console.WriteLine("in {0} years{1} you'll have the balance of {2}.",totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s", balance);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

now in the line

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} years{1} you'll have the balance of {2}.",totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s", balance);
```

i don't  understand why have the use {1} near the year means they are accessing **" ",totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s" "** this code , why are thee accessing this code and why they don't simply write

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} years you'll have the balance of {1}.",totalYears,balance);
```

but when i tried to compile the code by the above line the compiler gives the error :

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

why is this so? can any one explain?

Comment: Your alternative code looks fine to me. Can't see why it wouldn't compile. Are you sure you've posted the right code here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo and should say:

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} year{1} you'll have the balance of {2}.",totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s", balance);
```

The idea is to have it say `in 1 year...` or `in 2 years...` etc. The author made a mistake though and added an extra "s".

Comment: ok if it's only for putting s in the end of years then i should also work the below line 

Console.WriteLine("in {0} years you'll have the balance of {1}.",totalYears,balance);

but it's not working

Comment: @psnLoverCSharp That's because of your use of {2}. Change it to {1} and it will be fine. By the looks of it, you even corrected the error when posting the question as it says {1} there and will compile and work just fine like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} years{1} you'll have the balance of {2}.",totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s", balance);
```

The above line probably just has a typo and should be written without the "s" in years:

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} year{1} you'll have the balance of {2}.",totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s", balance);
```

As to why your line did not compile correctly is because you are called `{2}`, being the third item, which does not exist. The list starts at position `{0}` and you only have 2 items in the list. You could write it as

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} years you'll have the balance of {1}.", totalYears, balance);
```

...but then you wouldn't have the correct grammar when it is only '1 year'

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

> i don't understand why have the use {1} near the year means they are accessing " ",totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s" " this code , why are thee accessing this code and why they don't simply write

This is to do with English grammar. They are appending an `s` to the end of years if the value is not `1`. This is because in English you say `1 year`, `2 years`, `3 years` and so on. The code should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} year{1} you'll have the balance of {2}.", totalYears, totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s", balance);
```

You are getting the error you state because the placeholders should be incremental and equal to `number of args -1`. Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("in {0} years you'll have the balance of {1}.", totalYears, balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is just to differentiate between 1 entity and more than 1 entity

explaination :-

it is for applying "s" at the end of the "year" means if it is only 1 then it would be "year" else it is more than 1 it will be "years"

Answer (score 0):

the code `totalYears == 1 ? "" : "s"` says to put an 's' character if there is more or less than one year, otherwise an empty string.

this is so you dont get the line "in 1 years" which doesnt read very well